# Need to create dynamic thumbnail grid.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in web development, i need to create a website for portfolio purposes in which i need to show thumbnail and a little description of my project underneath it and all content should be dynamically displayed. I have basic knowledege of PHP, wordpress, javascript, jquery, python, and HTML/CSS so this i am doing for learning purpose.

I want you guys to please tell me the way how can i do it, just guide me rest of it i will handle.

Some similar examples are

http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=megafoliopro_jq

http://codecanyon.net/item/dzs-scroller-gallery-cool-jquery-media-gallery/full_screen_preview/457913?ref=ibrandstudio

I am new to this forum and expect someone will answer my question

Thanks a lot mates.

Comment: `I am new to this forum and expect someone will answer my question` <- What? Show some effort first please :)

Comment: You have it backwards, we don't tell you the way to go, we help you on the way after you have started.

Comment: Give us the fish, not the fishing rod.

Comment: Guys:) I tried nothing yet just roaming around and looking what is the best way to start it. That is why i posted it here :). @Cam I even dont want fishing rod i just want to know how to fish thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

Download [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/) and get either the [album](http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/projects/album) or [gallery](http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/projects/gallery/) module.  This is one out of many ways to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You could `glob()` a directory to generate your thumbnails using PHP.  I use this method on my photography site:

```
<?php
$counter = 0; // Set counter to 0
foreach (glob("images/photo-strip/thumb/*.jpg") as $pathToThumb) { // Grab files from the thumbnail path and save them to variable
    $th_filename = basename($pathToThumb); // Strip the thumbnail filename from the path
    $filename = str_replace('th_', '', $th_filename); // Strip th_ from the filename and save it to a different variable
    $pathToFull = 'images/photo-strip/' . $filename; // Rebuild the path to the full-size image
    echo ("<section class=\"photo-box\"><a href=\"$pathToFull\"><img src=\"$pathToThumb\" /></a></section>"); // Echo the photobox
    $counter++; // Increment counter by 1 until no file exists
}
?>
```

You could expand on this code some in order to generate your "captions" perhaps even style your captions off a `title=""` property inside the `<img>` tag.  How you match those captions up to the file is up to you.